How can I draw this in Latex
How can I draw like this 1 The problem is how can I colorize shape 2 like figure below 1.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,decorations.markings,angles,quotes}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}
\tikzset{declare function={x1=45;x2=60;x3=170;a=4.05;b=4;d=1;
c=sqrt(a^2-b^2);
h1(\u,\v)=(d*(c - a*cos(\u)*cos(\v)) + b^2*cos(\u))/(a - c*cos(\u)*cos(\v));
h2(\u,\v)=(b*sin(\u)*(a - d*cos(\v)))/(a - c*cos(\u)*cos(\v));
h3(\u,\v)=(b*sin(\v)*(c*cos(\u) - d))/(a - c*cos(\u)*cos(\v));
}}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,dotted/.style={dash pattern=on .03pt off 3pt,line cap=round}]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (F1) at (c,0,0);
\coordinate (F2) at (-c,0,0);
\draw[-latex,thick] (0,0,0)--(8,0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[-latex,thick] (0,0,0)--(0,8,0) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[-latex,thick] (0,0,0)--(0,0,8) node[above] {$z$};
\foreach \i in {0,90,...,360}{
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71]({h1(\x,\i)},{h2(\x,\i)},{h3(\x,\i)});
}
\foreach \j in {0,60,...,360}{
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=71]({h1(\j,\x)},{h2(\j,\x)},{h3(\j,\x)});
}
\fill[blue] (F1) circle (2pt);
\fill[red] (F2) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The result is


Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately, this is not how the site works. Questions that are basically "Can you do this complicated thing for me?" are generally not answered and are usually quickly closed. If you have started the diagram but you're stuck on some part, post the code you have so far and tell us where you're stuck. Otherwise, try to find something similar and modify it and then ask for help after you have some work to show.

I edit the question @SandyG

Now, what's your question, precisely? The blue area can be filled with \fill. The lines can be given a color like in \draw[red] …

I've tried that, but it doesn't give me the same result I want. It just fills the circles. @Bubaya
